# upload files that craw from website to ftp serve

Tags: python, web-crawler

I am making a crawler program.
And I had made crawler that craw news from the web page and It can upload to my local Computer but
I want to upload directly to FTP server.

I try to code a diverse way. but I can't...

My code is below
python

```
for i in range(0,len(a),2):
    url = defaultInformation['gooktoHome'] + a[i].attrs['href']
    r = requests.get(
          url, allow_redirects=True)
    fileName = datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
    # print(r.text)
    if(a[i].attrs['href'][-3:] == 'pdf'):
        ftp.storbinary('STOR ' + '/uh/backup/' + fileName + '.pdf',open(r.content))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved this problem using BytesIO
my code is below python

```py
for i in range(0,len(a),2):
    url = defaultInformation['gooktoHome'] + a[i].attrs['href']
    r = requests.get(
           url, allow_redirects=True)
    fileName = datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')

    if(a[i].attrs['href'][-3:] == 'pdf'):
        tFile = BytesIO(r.content)
        ftp.storbinary('STOR ' + '/uh/backup/' + fileName + '.pdf',tFile)
```